# Как циклом создавать новый df1, df2....dfn из каждой колонки и записывать новые df на разные листы эксель файла

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Всем привет. Пробую не "в руку" создавать df1 и т д. для каждого поля в исходном df

пока получилось только:

```
for i in df:
    df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns[:1]]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне в руку каждый раз не менять df.columns[:***1***] на плюс один для того чтобы создавать новый df.
И при этом ещё каждый из них сохранить в один эксель файл но на разные листы.

исходный df

|  | Вода | Хлеб | Молоко | Греча |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Влажность | -0.163172 | 0.0997964 | 0.078919 | -0.038507 |
| Температура | -0.08938 | -0.0729 | 0.070917 | -0.004910 |
| Давление 1 | -0.163172 | 0.0997964 | 0.078919 | -0.038507 |

новый df1 это поле влажность, температура, давление 1 + поле "Вода",
df2 это поле влажность, температура, давление 1 + поле "Хлеб"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем так всё сложно, но вот, например, собираем колонки в отдельные значения словаря, ключ - номер колонки:

```py
df_dict = {}
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    df_dict[i] = df.loc[:,col]
```

Можно, кстати, и без названий колонок тоже самое сделать, только по их номерам:

```py
df_dict = {}
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    df_dict[i] = df.iloc[:,i]
```